# Loading a String of JavaScript with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to take a string of JavaScript and load it as a resource with jQuery or by any other means? 
Ex.

```
var myScript = "window.myScript= window.myScript|| {}; 
(function() { 
     function myScript(foo) { 
          //do stuff 
     }
})(window);"
```

Take the above string, turn it into usable javascript

Comment: It's possible, but this raises another question, why would you want to this?

Comment: You can use `document.createElement('script')` and store the string into the element. Or you can call `eval()`.

Comment: BTW, Javascript doesn't allow you to break strings across lines like that.

Comment: A better solution would be saving the string as a file, then loading it asynchronously.

Comment: @AdamAzad For very strange values of "better", IMHO.

Comment: Dare I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Why are you passing an argument to the IIFE, but it doesn't have any variables in its parameter list.

Comment: @LionelRitchietheManatee Adam Azad dared, why shouldn't you?

Comment: The code above is purely cosmetic and is not syntactically correct :) I'm using WinJS.xhr to grab the google maps api js for a Windows Universal app. Using $.getScript doesn't work, win universal apps does not allow you to grab anything out side of the local context of the application.

Comment: I believe `$.getScript` uses `eval()`.

Comment: using WinJS.xhr return as json obj that has a response field that contains the api javascript in a string. Correct if i'm wrong, but using $.getScript requires a url to passed into it, which grab the script via web context which throws an exception for win universal apps. Using WinJS.xhr does not throw an exception , but the data I get back is diff. I get a json obj instead a script.

Comment: using eval() does seem to work! Thank to all who suggested using that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `eval` function for this:

```
  var myScript = 'window.myScript= window.myScript|| {}; 
   (function() { 
      function myScript(foo) { 
      //do stuff 
      }
   })(window);';

   eval(myScript);
```